# what is the significance of expressing Theta series as Eta-products?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I'm collection information for my upcoming project regarding eta-products and theta-series. I have the Günter Köhler's book,

[http://www.amazon.com/Products-Identities-Springer-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/3642161510](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642161510)

and read this research paper, as well

http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1617-14.pdf

My question here why people are interested in this kind of expression?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at my articles with Alex Berkovich, then click on his name, he has many more papers on the arXiv. http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Jagy_W/0/1/0/all/0/1